# trying to get the output and return code for "nc -vz <host> <port>" command using subprocess.Popen in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, netcat

In Python3 using subprocess.Popen, I would like to capture the output and command return code for this "nc -z 192.168.25.14 22" command.  Here is my sample code:
    `#!/usr/bin/env python
    import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
    import subprocess
    import time
    # set up null file for pipe messages
    nul_f = open('/dev/null', 'w')
    # try loop for clean breakout with cntl-C
    try:
      with open('/mnt/usbdrive/output/Urls.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split()
           commands = ['nc', '-vZ', data[1], data[0]]
            print(commands)
            try:
              ncdmp = subprocess.Popen(commands , stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
            except OSError:
              print ("error: popen")
              exit(-1) # if the subprocess call failed, there's not much point in continuing
            ncdmp.wait()
            if ncdmp.returncode != 0:
              print("  os.wait:exit status != 0\n")
            else:
              print ("os.wait:", ncdmp.pid, ncdmp.returncode)
            print("STDERR is ", ncdmp.stderr)
            print("STDOUT is ", ncdmp.stdout)
            print("STDIN is ", ncdmp.stdin)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print('Done', i)
    # clean up pipe stuff
    ncdmp.terminate()
    ncdmp.kill()
    nul_f.close()`

and an example of the output is

*Commands is  ['nc', '-vZ', '192.168.25.14', '22']

os.wait:exit status != 0

STDERR is  <_io.BufferedReader name=12>

STDOUT is  <_io.BufferedReader name=9>

STDIN is  <_io.BufferedWriter name=8>*

I'm assuming that I have an error in my code or logic, but I can not figure it out.  I have used similar code for other commands like ssh and ls without issues.  For this "nc" command I get the same set of output/messages regardless of whether or not there is an open port 22 at the host address.

Thanks...RDK

Comment: you need to use `stdout,stderr = ncdmp.communicate()` that will give you  what you want.

Comment: thanks.  I tried that, not 100% sure where in my code to insert this line, I tried after the subprocess line and before and after the wait line.  It made no difference in the output

Comment: If I print stdout or stderr, they are both null, ie zero length strings

Comment: if you run this NC command from a command line you get either a "success-like" message or a "failed like" message  depending on the existence of port 22 at the host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as I did not get any useful replies to this question, I changed the code from subprocess.Popen to subprocess.run as shown below.  This modification worked for my requirements as ncdup.stderr contained the information I was looking for.

```
      commands = shlex.split("nc -vz " + "-w 5 " + data[1] + " " + data[0])
      try:
        ncdmp = subprocess.run(commands , capture_output=True)
      except OSError:
          print ("error: popen")
        exit(-1) 
      err_line = str(ncdmp.stderr)
```